# Can't uncheck RadioButton if it's in its own group?

Tags: c#, wpf, radio-button

I have a set of radio buttons. In some cases I want the user to be able to select more than one of these radio buttons.

I use the logic that if I want the user to only select on of the radio buttons I add them to the same radiobuttongroup. If I want the user to be able to select mutltiple I add each one to thier own radiobuttongroup.

The issue I have is that when I select a radio button in a group by itself I can then not deselect it.

Could someone please advise why this is happening and suggest a different way of doing this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `CheckBoxes`. `RadioButtons` are *not* meant for this.

Comment: If you really must have your checkboxes looking like radio buttons (not really a good idea), you can create style for your checkboxes that resembles radio buttons if you need them to *look* a certain way.

Comment: @ChrisF: That'd be a pretty horrible thing to do, as most people know how RadioButtons are supposed to behave.

Answer (score 3):

Radiobuttons cant be unchecked. You have to use normal checkboxes in this context. In the Checked Event of the checkbox, you can for example uncheck another checkboxes. Its not a nice way, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

RadioButton in WFP has a boolean property `IsChecked`, which can be set to `false`. To reset radio buttons in a group you should set `IsChecked` to false for all (or just for a radio button which `IsChecked` is true).

Answer (score 0):

If you select the checked radio button the binding sets a value of true.  If the current value and proposed value are true then set it to false.  Hey it works for me.

```
    public bool chcked 
    {
        get { return c; }
        set 
        {
            if (c && value)
            {
                c = false;
                return;
            }
            c = value; 
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I remember I was able to do it on an old XAML/WPF project. Today I was looking for it implementing this on XAML/Windows Phone 8, and it seems that is kind of difficult to do.

Luckily I found this article:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f0f6587b-8a08-4c6c-b071-802d104a35da/how-to-uncheck-all-radiobuttons-in-a-group?forum=wpf

Basically,  you have to set IsChecked in False for all the buttons that are into the same Group. (BTW I have set IsThreeState in default value).

I hope this helps.

Cheers,
Herber